# Transferring parity blockchain data to another machine does not work

Tags: parity, synchronization, warp-sync, export

For the past several days I have been trying to transfer the blockchain data from an `x86_64` machine to an `armv7l` machine, hoping that I could avoid having to sync from scratch on the latter.

However, my pretty straightforward attempt to `rsync` the data has failed not only transferring from `x86_64` to `armv7l`, but also from `armv7l` to `x86_64`. The issue is the fact that neither parity will continue syncing with the transplanted data.

My first attempt was to simply rsync the `~/.local/share/io.parity.ethereum/chains` directory. Upon transferring the data, parity on the other machine was not able to continue syncing newly mined blocks and simply stalled. After some time, parity would display the following error: `Stage 5 block verification failed`

Being quite ignorant of parity's internals, my thought was that the blockchain data was dependant on some other file as a verification measure? To try and solve that, I simply transferred over the entire `io.parity.ethereum` directory. That would also fail with the same error.

After that, I thought that the issue was some kind of unique verification hash generated from device's architectural differences, which made me try and find a way to export the blockchain. This is possible via the `parity export blocks` command, but unfortunately it will not export everything until the device has completed syncing "ancient blocks" with the following message: `Error exporting incomplete chain` as per https://github.com/paritytech/parity/issues/6933

My question is whether this is an intentional security measure, or some kind of transfer issue?

There isn't any transfer error during the procedure, and I have used an USB flash drive formatted with `btrfs` to transfer the data. Both devices are able to sync from scratch on their own.

- rsync flags: `-a --info=progress2 --update --recursive --delete`
- parity flags: `--ipc-path=/run/ethereum/parity.ipc --scale-verifiers`
- parity version: `v1.9.0.10818` built from git master on both machines

Any kind of insight into this issue is greatly appreciated!